# how to add SimpleExoPlayerView in notification

Tags: android, notifications, exoplayer

I'm trying to add `SimpleExoPlayerView` Controls on **Lock Screen** and **Notifications**.
I want to create notification player control when start play music on activity.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/close"/>
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/audio_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/notf_playback_control"
        app:hide_on_touch="false"
        app:show_timeout="0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i maked app play mp3 using exoplayer but when i need to add SimpleExoPlayerView to notification for control music pause or play for background control i can't. i hope you help me. thanks a lot...

Comment: Only certain `View`s are allowed in `Notification` layouts, since they use `RemoteViews`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout.

Comment: this link describe how to :https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b